# Faster kNN Classification Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I want to code my own kNN algorithm from scratch, the reason is that I need to weight the features. The problem is that my program is still really slow despite removing for loops and using built in numpy functionality.

Can anyone suggest a way to speed this up? I don't use `np.sqrt` for the L2 distance because it's unnecessary and actually slows it all up quite a bit.

```
class GlobalWeightedKNN:
    """
    A k-NN classifier with feature weights

    Returns: predictions of k-NN.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.X_train = None
        self.y_train = None
        self.k = None
        self.weights = None
        self.predictions = list()

    def fit(self, X_train, y_train, k, weights):        
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.y_train = y_train
        self.k = k
        self.weights = weights

    def predict(self, testing_data):
        """
        Takes a 2d array of query cases.

        Returns a list of predictions for k-NN classifier
        """

        np.fromiter((self.__helper(qc) for qc in testing_data), float)  
        return self.predictions


    def __helper(self, qc):
        neighbours = np.fromiter((self.__weighted_euclidean(qc, x) for x in self.X_train), float)
        neighbours = np.array([neighbours]).T 
        indexes = np.array([range(len(self.X_train))]).T
        neighbours = np.append(indexes, neighbours, axis=1)

        # Sort by second column - distances
        neighbours = neighbours[neighbours[:,1].argsort()]  
        k_cases = neighbours[ :self.k]
        indexes = [x[0] for x in k_cases]

        y_answers = [self.y_train[int(x)] for x in indexes]
        answer = max(set(y_answers), key=y_answers.count)  # get most common value
        self.predictions.append(answer)


    def __weighted_euclidean(self, qc, other):
        """
        Custom weighted euclidean distance

        returns: floating point number
        """

        return np.sum( ((qc - other)**2) * self.weights )
```

Comment: KNN is a very slow algorithm in prediction (O(n*m) per sample) anyway (unless you go towards the path of just finding approximate neighbours using things like KD-Trees, LSH and so on...). But still, your implementation can be improved by, for example, avoiding having to store all the distances and sorting. Instead, you could keep a priority queue (heaps, have a look at the `heapq` module) with size K, and store there only the current closest neighbours.

Comment: You haven't removed the for-loops, you've just put them in generator expressions. This is still an O[N^2] algorithm... both scipy and scikit-learn have tree-based nearest-neighbors algorithms that will be O[Nlog(N)]. I would suggest using one of those.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I must apologies sorry, I should have specified that I require the guaranteed nearest neighbours, so KD Trees etc. wont' cut it unfortunately. Even though the list comprehensions aren't really eliminating for loops, they're incredibly faster than an explicit one here right? Thanks for the tip on the priority queue, I hadn't considered that, the major bottleneck is having to compute all the L2 distances however... not so much the sorting.

Answer (score 14):

Scikit-learn uses a KD Tree or Ball Tree to compute nearest neighbors in `O[N log(N)]` time. Your algorithm is a direct approach that requires `O[N^2]` time, and also uses nested for-loops within Python generator expressions which will add significant computational overhead compared to optimized code.

If you'd like to compute weighted k-neighbors classification using a fast `O[N log(N)]` implementation, you can use `sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier` with the weighted minkowski metric, setting `p=2` (for euclidean distance) and setting `w` to your desired weights. For example:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

model = KNeighborsClassifier(metric='wminkowski', p=2,
                             metric_params=dict(w=weights))
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predicted = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had no idea that there was this option in sklearn. I just tested it with the "brute" algorithm (my approach) and interestingly it actually takes 4782sec instead of 2079sec with mine. However the KD Tree is incredibly fast, for sure when I'm using extremely big datasets I will default to this option rather than using my implementation, even though it's not guaranteed to find the nearest neighbours, it's damn close. Thanks!

Comment: The KD-tree/Ball tree is an exact algorithm, so it is guaranteed to find the nearest neighbors.

Comment: Forgive me but I don't think that's true is it? Otherwise what's even the point of having the option of a 'brute' algorithm in sklearn? Everywhere I read tells me that kd_tree and ball_tree are not guaranteed to find the nearest neighbours, but pretty close ones.

Comment: Late reply with more information: the kdtree and ball_tree are indeed guaranteed to find the exact nearest neighbors. The reason `"brute"` exists is for two reasons: (1) brute force is faster for small datasets, and (2) it's a simpler algorithm and therefore useful for testing. You can confirm that the algorithms are directly compared to each other in the [sklearn unit tests](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/88be2abb7b7f7450dc569e0065e672a0676e4130/sklearn/neighbors/tests/test_neighbors.py#L72-L96).

Answer (score 7):

you can take a look at this great article introducing `faiss`
[Make kNN 300 times faster than Scikit-learn’s in 20 lines!](https://towardsdatascience.com/make-knn-300-times-faster-than-scikit-learns-in-20-lines-5e29d74e76bb)
it is on **GPU** and developed in **CPP** behind the seen

```py
import numpy as np
import faiss


class FaissKNeighbors:
    def __init__(self, k=5):
        self.index = None
        self.y = None
        self.k = k

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(X.shape[1])
        self.index.add(X.astype(np.float32))
        self.y = y

    def predict(self, X):
        distances, indices = self.index.search(X.astype(np.float32), k=self.k)
        votes = self.y[indices]
        predictions = np.array([np.argmax(np.bincount(x)) for x in votes])
        return predictions
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your class and using `BallTree` data structure (with build time `O(n.(log n)^2)`, refer to https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1210/1210.6122.pdf) with custom `DistanceMetric` (since Callable functions in the metric parameter are NOT supported for `KDTree`, as mentioned here as a note: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html), you can use the following code too (also removing the loop for prediction):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
from scipy.stats import mode

class GlobalWeightedKNN:
    """
    A k-NN classifier with feature weights

    Returns: predictions of k-NN.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.X_train = None
        self.y_train = None
        self.k = None
        self.weights = None
        self.tree = None
        self.predictions = list()

    def fit(self, X_train, y_train, k, weights):        
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.y_train = y_train
        self.k = k
        self.weights = weights
        self.tree = BallTree(X_train, \
                             metric=DistanceMetric.get_metric('wminkowski', p=2, w=weights))

    def predict(self, testing_data):
        """
        Takes a 2d array of query cases.

        Returns a list of predictions for k-NN classifier
        """
        indexes = self.tree.query(testing_data, self.k, return_distance=False)
        y_answers = self.y_train[indexes]
        self.predictions = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: mode(x)[0], 1, y_answers)
        return self.predictions
```

Training:

```
from time import time
n, d = 10000, 2
begin = time()
cls = GlobalWeightedKNN()
X_train = np.random.rand(n,d)
y_train = np.random.choice(2,n, replace=True)
cls.fit(X_train, y_train, k=3, weights=np.random.rand(d))
end = time()
print('time taken to train {} instances = {} s'.format(n, end - begin))
# time taken to train 10000 instances = 0.01998615264892578 s
```

Testing / prediction:

```
begin = time()
X_test = np.random.rand(n,d)
cls.predict(X_test)
end = time()
print('time taken to predict {} instances  = {} s'.format(n, end - begin))
#time taken to predict 10000 instances  = 3.732935905456543 s
```